# Is it possible to find available services like cabs in current location using gps in iPhone

Tags: iphone, gps, clgeocoder

I am developing an Application, which should give the available taxi or cabs at the current location in the city, here, what i have done is, i found the current location(address) using  Reverse CLGeocoder. To get the available resources, whether i should make use of any api, or something else. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no available API as far I know.. you can get in touch with cab providers in your location and ask them to provide feeds about their cabs. Then you can create a centralized server which will give you the response.

The idea is good but you will need some investors on your side and some expertise with server set up and a marketing guy who can rope in all these cab providers.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I'm having doubt here, App users might be in various locations and in several cities, then how could i collect the information and setup the server to retrieve and display the info gathered.

Comment: you will need info from various cities , so what you can do is start from a couple of cities and if things go well you can extend this to other cities

Comment: Ok, i will try it and i hope will works. Thank you Ankit.